# &= operator in javascript to reduce booleans

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an efficient function using idiomatic C style, and I have some <s>concerns</s> curiosity about the <s>correctness</s> performance.

I have a function which takes a list of class strings and what it does is it walks up the DOM hierarchy matching nodes against the list of class strings. A check passes only if all of the class strings match with the element's `className` prop.

So...

```
function nearestParent(elem, clasz, stopat) {
  // stopat can be used to stop the search short. For speed.
  // make sure you do not use jquery elements
  if (typeof clasz === 'string') { clasz = [clasz]; }
  do {
    elem = elem.parentNode;
    for(var i=0,l=clasz.length,pass=true, cn=elem.className;i<l;++i) {
      pass &= ~cn.indexOf(clasz[i]);
    }
    if(pass) return elem;
  } while (elem && elem != stopat);
}
```

The for loop as you can see here is basically checking for string matches using `indexOf`. However the pitfall that I see is that if the value returned by indexOf is odd, pass gets set to the wrong value: `~3 & 1` = `0`.

So it seems like a correct implementation would be `pass &= cn.indexOf(clasz[i]) != -1;` or perhaps `pass &= !!~cn.indexOf(clasz[i]);`... I wonder which way is fastest?

Comment: now, I would say more than half of the developers wouldn't know what &= is. So for maintainability I would suggest not to use them. If performance is an issue then use something like javascript compiler to optimize your code :)

Comment: I'd be surprised if the difference was worth the effort; it also wouldn't surprise me if you wouldn't be better off just using a normal `if` and broke the loop (or even just did the `return`) when you find a hit.

Comment: What on earth are you doing here? Why do you think that such fugly code is a good idea? If I found this function in our codebase, I'd tear it up and rewrite it in a way that can actually be understood. Too clever, but not in a good way.

Comment: If you want to know which is fastest *(I guess that's your question here)*, test it in the browsers you care about. It could very well be that the outcome will be different for different implementations.

Comment: `className` or `classNode`? You seem confused.

Comment: ...and your class comparison can produce false positives, so you may want to work on that before you bother optimizing.

Comment: Hmm yes this function doesnt work well yet. @spender. Close, I'm not confused, I was just rushed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on the Chrome team at Google. I don't work on the JavaScript engine directly, but I do know a lot about how the DOM is implemented.

I doubt differences such as `x &= y != -1` and `x &= !!~y` will impact performance of this loop significantly. Probably `y != -1` is better. The following things are probably more important:

- Execute fewer iterations of the loop by exiting early when `pass` is false.
- See if other DOM APIs are more effective. For example, use [Element.classList.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) instead of indexOf to test whether an element has a particular class name. Or depending on which browsers you are targeting, construct a CSS selector and use [Element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches) to test whether each element matches the selector.
- Use a profiler (Chrome [has one built in](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling)) to measure your script and measure directly what's fast and slow.

Answer (score 0):

The `&=` operator is the bitwise and operator. It will convert both operands to 32 bit integers and do a bitwise and operation on them.

You would rather use the `&&` operator, which is the logical and operator:

```
pass = pass && cn.indexOf(clasz[i]) != -1;
```

The `&&` does short circuit evaluation, so it would stop evaluating the second operand as soon as `pass` becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.time) or just compare two before and after Dates on a few hundred iterations.

Although you should also factor in the potential for wasted time die to a loss of readability.